# LinearModelFit with Dataset

Tags: dataset

I have a rectangular dataset, initially created with `SemanticImport` of a CSV file and then manipulated.  Rather surprisingly, `LinearModelFit` does not seem able to work directly with a dataset. Am I overlooking something? Do I need to produce the associated data matrix?  If so, what is the most efficent approach to that?  I'm currently using `Values /@ Normal[dataset]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`LinearModelFit` does not presently (v11.0.1) operate directly upon datasets:

```
$ds = SemanticImportString["1,2\n4,5\n10,20\n", {"Integer", "Integer"}]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

```
LinearModelFit[$ds, x, x]
```

[image: error message]

We can, however, invoke `LinearModelFit` as a query operator:

```
$ds[LinearModelFit[#, x, x] &]
```

[image: fitted model]

It is probably not worth the trouble, but if we have are hearts set upon direct application of `LinearModelFit` then we can supply the definition ourselves:

```
Dataset;
Unprotect[Dataset];

Dataset /: LinearModelFit[ds_Dataset?Dataset`ValidDatasetQ, rest___] :=
  LinearModelFit[Normal@ds, rest]

Protect[Dataset];
```

So then:

```
LinearModelFit[$ds, x, x]
```

[image: fitted model]

**Update**

If the original CSV data includes headers, then the imported structure will be a list of associations:

```
$ds2 = SemanticImportString["x,y\n1,2\n4,5\n10,20\n", {"Integer", "Integer"}]
```

[image: dataset with headers]

Since `LinearModelFit` cannot work with associations, with have little option but to convert those associations to lists.  For example, using a query:

```
$ds[Values /* (LinearModelFit[#, x, x] &)]
```

[image: fitted model]

... or direct application (with the extra definition in place):

```
LinearModelFit[$ds2[Values], x, x]
```

[image: fitted model]

Both of these options offer only a meager improvement over the notation proposed in the question (i.e. the omission of `Normal`).  To dispense with the use of `Values` would require that `LinearModelFit` accept lists of associations.  This time the return is even smaller in comparison to the effort involved, but we can arrange it if we wish:

```
LinearModelFit;
Unprotect[LinearModelFit];

PrependTo[DownValues[LinearModelFit]
, HoldPattern[LinearModelFit[data:{_Association..}, rest__]] :>
  LinearModelFit[Values[data], rest]
];

Protect[LinearModelFit];
```

So then:

```
$ds2[LinearModelFit[#, x, x] &]
```

[image: fitted model]

```
LinearModelFit[$ds2, x, x]
```

[image: fitted model]

Comment: Note that this definition will not quite work if the dataset has column headers (so that its `Normal` form is a list of associations, not a list of lists).  Is there a simpler way than the one I mentioned in the question to extract the numerical matrix in this case?

Comment: Yes, you are right: the alternate formulations offer only a marginal notational convenience when the original data has headers.  While we can dispense with `Normal`, we are still stuck with `Values`.  It is _possible_ to do more (see my update), but it feels like diminishing returns are setting in.  Perhaps WRI will apply these changes in some future release.