# How to: `GeneralizedLinearModelFit` with `Dataset` with cofactors

Tags: fitting, dataset

Please do not think of this question as a more general extension of [LinearModelFit with Dataset](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131568/linearmodelfit-with-dataset) asked by [@alan](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/19530/alan), and [answered](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/131570/42578) by [@Weach](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/142/wreach).

The [original question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131568/linearmodelfit-with-dataset) (or at least the [solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/131570/42578)) pertained more to how to overload `LinearModelFit` to work on [`Dataset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html).

While overloading [`GeneralLinaerModelFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeneralizedLinearModelFit.html) for [`Dataset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html) would be nice; here, however, the question is more in relation to "data wrangling" / how to input my data to get the desired results.

Suppose you have a [`Dataset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html) as follows:

```
numberOfRecords = 100;  (* records in the dataset *)

numberOfGroups = 2;    (* groups:    g1,...,gn *)
numberOfSegments = 4;  (* segments:  s1,...,sn *)
numberOfCofactors = 3; (* cofactors: c1,...,cn *)
numberOfFeatures = 5;  (* features  x1,...,xn *)


(* in this case binary *)    
responseVector = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {numberOfRecords, 1}];
groupVector = RandomInteger[{1, numberOfGroups}, {numberOfRecords, 1}];
segmentVector =  
  RandomInteger[{1, numberOfSegments}, {numberOfRecords, 1}];

featureMatrix = 
  RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {numberOfRecords, numberOfFeatures}];
cofactorMatrix = 
  RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {numberOfRecords, numberOfCofactors}];


(* join data together *)
data = Table[
   Join[
    responseVector[[r]], 
    groupVector[[r]],
    segmentVector[[r]],
    featureMatrix[[r]],
    cofactorMatrix[[r]]
    ], {r, numberOfRecords}
   ];

(* construct header *)
header = Join[
  {"y", "g", "s"},
  Table["x" <> ToString[i], {i, 1, numberOfFeatures}], 
  Table["c" <> ToString[i], {i, 1, numberOfCofactors}]
  ]

(* map header to each record *)
assoc = AssociationThread[header, #] & /@ data;
(* make dataset *)
ds = Dataset@assoc;
```

The goal is to do the following:

per group, taking into account the cofactors, predict the response at each segment.

So the result should look something like this (given the demo data)

[image]

From the Details and Options tab of the documents, I can not really see how I should format my data to get the results I am looking for.
Any help and explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you plan to "predict the response at each segment.". I don't really want to dig to figure out how you expect that to happen (and I'm guessing not many others want to either).